# Unknown hostname for the hosts on the same LAN

Tags: router, dns, ip, modem

Edit: I tried `raspberrypi.local` and `raspberrypi.` same result for both.

I am not very experienced in networking. However, i know some fundamentals.

Now, I do have one Raspberry Pi and one laptop connected to same WiFi in my home.

The hostnames are raspberrypi and laptop1.

When I check 192.168.1.1 (modem interface) I can see that both devices are connected to wifi, and their hostnames are correctly identified there.

The ip numbers are:

raspberrypi 192.168.1.40

laptop1 192.168.1.35

Then I think that if I make a ping from my laptop, addressing raspberrypi, as follows

```
ping raspberrypi
```

The DNS should resolve name raspberrypi to the ip (192.168.1.40) and it should work fine. However, that is not the case. I get unknown host raspberrypi warning.

On the other hand, I am able to ping raspberrypi by `ping 192.168.1.40`.

This is also valid for ssh or nslookup, etc.

I don't understand why my router cannot resolve those hostnames and let my pc know about it.

I think I might have some conceptual misunderstanding. So, I will be waiting for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `ping raspberrypi.` (with ending dot).

Comment: @harrymc nope, same again

Comment: The DNS mechanism is not being used. The simplest solution would be to use a `hosts` file.

Comment: @harrymc yes but that way I have to assign static IP to devices. Why dns mechanism is not used? Can I make it work?

Comment: try raspberrypi.local

Comment: @Laif tried already, no use

Comment: well, the first problem is that a DNS server must have a zone (a domain that it serves names and addresses for). so I can resolve systems in my domain hostname.xyz.com. the hostnames displayed on the router are just hostnames. do you actually have a DNS server on your network, and do all your clients point to it as their dns server? have you added a zone to the server for your internal domain?

Answer (score 2):

Most routers contain a built-in DHCP server and a built-in DNS server, but very few routers make those two processes talk to each other. So when you see that your router "knows" that host "raspberrypi" has address 192.168.1.40, you're really just seeing what the DHCP server knows. Because the two built-in server processes don't talk to each other, the DNS server has no idea who "raspberrypi" is or what its IPv4 address is, so it can't answer that question when queried via the DNS protocol.

So you probably need to manually enter those name-to-address mappings in the DNS server administration UI in your router, or use some other name resolution system (such as IETF ZeroConf a.k.a. mDNS) so that devices on your network can look up each others' IP addresses by name.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will have a look at those you mentioned.